# Urn with b*r balls

Tags: probability

I have an urn with b blue balls and r red balls, what is the probability that the two balls will have the same color. I need to solve this problem with replacement and without replacement. This is my attempt at a solution. Without replacement, we add the probabilities of the balls both being blue and the balls both being red. That is, the final probability would be $\frac{b(b-1)+r(r-1)}{br}$. With replacement, the final probability would be $\frac{b*b+r*r}{br}$. Is my logic correct in determining the probability?

Comment: With replacement it would just be (b+r)(b+r)?

Comment: Yes, for replacement it is $(b+r)(b+r)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No total ways $${b+r\choose 2}$$ so probability will be $\frac{(b)(b-1)+(r)(r-1)}{(b+r)(b+r-1)}$ same for other one